# What is the codomain of a natural transformation $\alpha : F \Rightarrow G$?

Tags: category-theory

... and (when, if ever) does it matter?

It could be:

1. the set of objects in the target category of F and G
2. the set of objects in Im(G)
3. Im(G)

I think (2) is most intuitive.

Update: There was some ambiguity in the question. In the *functor category* [C, D] the co-domain of a natural transformation $\alpha$ is just an object $G$. But in *implementing* $\alpha$ we require a function mapping $FX \to GX$ for all X in the source category. The image of this function of X is clearly the set of all objects in the target category Y for which there exists an $\alpha_x :FX \to Y$. The codomain of this function of X is unclear (and apparently not interesting at all except as a tool for satisfying category axioms of [C,D]).

Comment: A natural transformation is a collection of morphisms in the target category, though. If you want to see it as a morphism in the category of functors, then its image could perhaps be thought in [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(category_theory)) terms.

Comment: None of the above. The codomain is $G$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Because it is collection of morphisms in dom(F)=dom(G), I thought of it is a function between objects in the codomain.

Comment: The "concrete implementation" of a natural transformation can be thought of as a function sending objects in the domain of $F$ (or $G$) to morphisms in the codomain of $F$ (or $G$), yes. But a natural transformation should be thought of as a morphism in the category of functors, so its domain and codomain are functors.

Comment: @ZhenLin Ok, so people just immediately abstract. So the codomain of $\Rightarrow$ is the source category and the Im(G), which is closest to my option (3) above, i.e. $cod(\alpha) = (dom(G), Im(G))$? Sorry for sticking to implementations.  I am still thinking that two functors F, H naturally transform to G if and only if both "concrete implementations" of F and G are functions with common codomain ob(Im(G)).

Comment: @Gae.S. Beautiful. Thanks. So a natural transformation can have an image object! Intuitively, I guess this image object $I$ must also be in the functor category.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the update. The component of $\alpha$ at $X$, $\alpha_X$, is a morphism $FX\to GX$, so the codomain is $GX$.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I have tried to clarify!

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. The image of the mapping $X\mapsto \alpha_X$ is a collection of morphisms, not objects. I can't tell if you've misunderstood the definition of a natural transformation, or if you're trying to ask for a  notion of codomain that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A morphism only has a codomain in the category in which it is a morphism; there is simply no other answer for the codomain of $\alpha$ but $G$, regardless of how it's implemented.

It looks like you believe that $\alpha$ has codomain $G$ in $[C,D]$, but that it must have some other kind of codomain in some other category; it appears you perhaps want this category to be the category of sets, but it's hard to tell. The point, though, is that perhaps the set theoretic object $X\mapsto\alpha_X$ can be made into a morphism in some other category (presumably you have in mind something other than the function $\mathrm{Ob}(C)\to\mathrm{Mor}(D)$), but there's no hope of answering what its codomain is until you can tell us *what category* you think it's a morphism in. And if it's not $[C,D]$, then you've answered a different question than "what's the codomain of the *natural transformation* $\alpha$?"

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand how to use the terms precisely.

Comment: I was thinking of the components of a natural transformation as a good old fashioned function - not really thinking categorically - taking objects of the image of F to objects of the image of G.

Comment: Meaning a function taking the set of objects of the image of F to some objects of the image of G.

Comment: Right. It might be helpful to see that the relation $\{\langle dom(\alpha_X),cod(\alpha_X\rangle\;|\;X\in C\}$ not only doesn't determine a unique natural transformation (it will be the same relation for any natural transformation), but needn't even be functional (if the object mapping of $F$ isn't injective). It really is a somewhat different beast than you might be used to seeing.